# SQL Query across several tables in SalesForce

Tags: sql, sql-server, salesforce

The question that I am trying get get the data for is-

“I want to know when an Opportunity that has been influenced by a  Marketing campaign is associated with an Account. There could be several contacts for the Account
So if ANY Contact is associated with a Campaign (Member of a campaign)- Tell me what Account the (or Those) Contact(s) is connected to, 
and if there is an Opportunity  associated with the account, 
and if there is an Opportunity  associated with the Account the Opportunity was created after the Contact  was associated with the campaign”

I cant figure out the logic. I am new to SQL. ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using SQL Server 2012

I have 5 relevant tables from a SalesForce database –

Account Table (PK ID, OpportunityID), Opportunity Table (PK ID, AccountID ), Contact Table (PK ID, AccountID), Campaign Table (PK ID, ContactID, ParentID), CampaignMember Table (PK ID, ContactID, CampaignID)

This link gives the SalesForce Data Model
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm

This is what I have come up with, but it returns no rows.

```
SELECT O.CreatedDate OppCreatedDate
,o.Name as OpportunityName
,a.Name AccountName
,c.Name as ContactName
,ca.Name as CampaignName
,o.Amount_Software
,o.CreatedDate
FROM Opportunity o
INNER JOIN Account a on a.Id = o.AccountID 
LEFT JOIN  Contact c ON c.AccountId = a.Id
INNER JOIN CampaignMember cm ON cm.CampaignID  = c.ID
INNER JOIN Campaign ca ON ca.ID = cm.CampaignID
LEFT JOIN Campaign ca2 ON ca2.ID = ca.ParentID
WHERE o.CreatedDate > cm.CreatedDate
ORDER BY AccountName DESC;
```

Thank You.

Comment: How are you executing this query?  Salesforce has its own database querying language called SOQL.  Unless you have imported data from Salesforce into SQL Server the T-SQL that you've written won't work.

Comment: There is a Replica database I can connect SQL Server 2012 to. I can use SQL Server to query the data....I just cant figure out how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running an INNER JOIN on a LEFT JOIN, which is ambiguous.

Opportunity <--> Account
Account --> Contact
**Campaign Member <--> Contact** (this should be a left-join because of the line above)
**Campaign Member <--> Campaign** (this should be a left join because of the line two-above)
Campaign --> Campaign

The visual for this is here (you can't inner-join a new table to a left-joined table):

GOOD:
INNER JOIN <--> INNER JOIN --> LEFT JOIN --> LEFT JOIN

BAD:
INNER JOIN <--> INNER JOIN --> LEFT JOIN --> INNER JOIN

Comment: Thanks.  Ok, I see that and understand, but I think I still do not have the right query structure.  I expect to get Account names, and EVERY Contact associated with that account,  who have at least one contact who is a Campaign member; The Campaign Name that the contact is a member of, AND if there is an Opportunity associated with the Account- The opportunity Name.

Comment: Until you fix your joins, you'll get no data returned.  Once you fix the joins, then you can troubleshoot further.

Comment: I have the query.  I have limited the data to one account only for simplicity.  I think I am close now.  It is returning data that I think is correct, but I am not sure.  Here is what I have now.

Comment: 'SELECT DISTINCT c.Name ContactName
,a.Name AccountName
,o.Name OppName
,o.CreatedDate OppCreatedDate
,ca.Name CampaignName
FROM Contact c 
INNER JOIN CampaignMember cm ON cm.ContactId = c.Id
INNER JOIN Account a ON a.Id = c.AccountId
INNER JOIN Contact c2 ON c2.AccountId = a.Id
INNER JOIN Campaign ca ON ca.Id = cm.CampaignId
RIGHT JOIN Opportunity o ON o.AccountId = a.Id
WHERE o.CreatedDate > cm.CreatedDate AND a.Name LIKE 'National Oilwell Varco'
ORDER BY c.Name DESC;'

Comment: I meant to say I rebuilt the query- and sorry for the formating.  I could not indent for some reason

Comment: @BeRye -- Observations: 1) table c2 is in your FROM, but it's not being used; 2) should o be LEFT JOINed?; and 3) just for the sake of convenience, "Name" is not a good field name because it is a key word -- you may need to bracket it with square brackets: o.[Name], etc.

Comment: I see that now.  I have deleted c2. Yes o should be a left join I think. I will keep working on this.  I think I am understanding the joins better with you help.  I am still struggling with getting the right data.